# Reactive Elasticsearch and Paging

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, project-reactor, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using a Reactive client for Elasticsearch. Both of them (`ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate` or `ReactiveCrudRepository`) have support for Flux/Mono and this is working fine for me.

My current problem is that using ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate:

```
return reactiveElasticsearchTemplate.search(
    new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10))
        .build(),
    UserDocument.class
)
```

It is returning slice, but I don't have any information about `total elements`, as method signature returns `Flux<SearchHit<UserDocument>>`. Ideally, I would like to get `SearchHits` or something similar, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

Currently this information is not available in the reactive implementation there is an [open issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-796) for that. The only possibility at the moment is sending a count request first.